# Jquery hover show hide with multiple related items

Tags: jquery, hover, hide, show

First of all: I am just starting to work with JS/Jquery. So please excuse any potential rookie mistakes.
Now to the issue.

I have an item(a) with an hidden `item(hidden_a).` When i hover over `item(a) item(hidden_a)` shows up. So far so easy. But now i have several of this items on the page (for example: 10). Now is the question: How can i change my jquery snippet to success without writing the same snippets 10 times for 10 different selectors. Or is this even possible?

Thank you

Here the code:

```
 <ul >
            <li class="trigger"><a href="" >Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="trigger"><a href=""  >Item 2</a></li>

        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li style="display:none" class="target">
                <p >Hidden Item to Item 1</p>
            </li>
            <li  style="display:none" class="target">
                <p>Hidden Item to Item 2</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

<script>

$(".target").hide();
$(".trigger").hover(function(){
   $(".target").show();
},function(){
   $(".target").hide();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add for the outer element (a in your case) a class called `outer`, and for the inner elements add `inner`.

```
$(".outer").hover(function()
{
    //alert( $(this).find(".inner").show());
    $(this).find(".inner").show()
});

$(".outer").mouseleave(function()
{
    $(this).find(".inner").hide();
});
```

**Make sure** that the initial state of the `.inner` element is `display: none`.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/82weU/2/

Comment: Thank you 4 your quick answer. But this didnt work at all :) But maybe i did wrong at some place. Maybe you could specify your advice. Thx

Comment: Awesome. Big big thanks. (I updated the fiddle with your suggestion about (mouseleave). ) http://jsfiddle.net/82weU/4/

Comment: You can see my fiddle with multiple divs. No problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper around each `trigger` and its corresponding `target`. Then you can look inside this wrapper for the corresponding target.

If you can't change the html structure, you can work with `.index()` https://api.jquery.com/index/ and `.eq()` https://api.jquery.com/eq/: Find the index of the hovered trigger and with its help the corresponding target.

Example code:

```
var $triggers = $(".trigger");
var $targets = $(".target").hide();

$triggers.hover(function(){
    var $currentTrigger = $(this);
    var indexOfTrigger = $triggers.index();
    var $correspondingTarget = $targets.eq(indexOfTrigger);
    $correspondingTarget.show();
},function(){
    var $currentTrigger = $(this);
    var indexOfTrigger = $triggers.index();
    var $correspondingTarget = $targets.eq(indexOfTrigger);
    $correspondingTarget.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks really big. I will take a deeper look at your solution when i am better with Jquery and JS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but heres another solution using index() and nth-child() that I think falls closer to what you might be looking for. Also the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S4aa9/

```
$(".hidden li").hide();
$(".trigger li").mouseenter(function(){
    //gets the nth position of the li
    var pos = $(this).index()+1;    
    $('.hidden li:nth-child('+pos+')').show();  
});

$('.trigger li').mouseleave(function(){
    var pos = $(this).index()+1;    
    $('.hidden li:nth-child('+pos+')').hide();
});
```

Comment: I dont get some parts of the code, but the result is also stunning too :) Thank you. I really need to learn some more.